# Navigation Drawer Group Title when Items populated Dynamically

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am using the standard Navigation Drawer in my app to display two kind of menu items:

1. High level general items like Dashboard, Detail View etc.
2. Specific screens for each user account.

The second group of items needs to be populated dynamically i.e. I cannot specify these in the XML. I am struggling with getting a title on the second group.

This is my current menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="General">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@+id/main_group"
                android:orderInCategory="1">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
                    android:title="@string/nav_dashboard"
                    android:checkable="true"
                    android:checked="true"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav_all"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
                    android:title="@string/nav_all"
                    android:checkable="true" />
            </group>

        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="Accounts">
        <menu>
            <group
                android:id="@+id/accounts_group"
                android:orderInCategory="2">

            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

The title `Accounts` is not visible on my navigation drawer. However, if I don't populate the items dynamically but put some random items in the XML, it is visible.

This is how I am populating the menu items:

```
for (int index = 0; index < accountsList.size(); index++) {
    MainActivityPresenter.AccountInfo accountInfo = accountsList.get(index);
    menu.add(R.id.accounts_group, index + MENU_ITEM_ID, 1, accountInfo.name).setCheckable(true);
}
```

Looking for a hint. Why is the item title `Accounts` not showing when I add items dynamically? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to change your menu XML layout like the one below, in this way the titles will not be selectable and only sub-items can be checked.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:title="General"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:id="@+id/general_menu">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_dashboard"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_dashboard"
            android:title="@string/nav_dashboard"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_all"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
            android:title="@string/nav_all"/>
    </menu>
</item>
<item android:title="Accounts"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:id="@+id/accounts_group">
    <menu>
        <!-- filled at runtime -->
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Then in your code you need to access the correct menu `item` which for us is like a "logical group", and you can use this code to do this:

```
//use the index of the group, in your case Account item is the 2nd in the
//XML this means its index is 1    
val menuItem: MenuItem = navigationView.menu.getItem(1)
//save the generated view Id, because if you need a reference after you need 
//to save newSubMenuId property somewhere before adding the item
val newSubMenuId = View.generateViewId()
//add the item to the submenu. The order value it's used to position the
//item inside the group. With 1 it will be the first item, 2 will be the second and so on
val addedItem = menuItem.subMenu.add(Menu.NONE, newSubMenuId, 1, R.string.new_account)
//add a nice icon to the inserted sub-item
addedItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_account_icon)
```

Now you will have a problem, without `group`s in your menu XML, you will not able to use the `android:checkableBehavior="single"` property to prevent multi-selection of items in your `NavigationView`.

To solve this last problem we can do this:

```
val navigationView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener { selectedItem ->

    //loop trough all the main items (which are groups for us) to remove the checked state
    for (i in 0 until navigationView.menu.size()) {
        val menuItem = navigationView.menu.getItem(i)
        menuItem.isChecked = false
        if (menuItem.hasSubMenu()) {
            //if they have a subMenu, loop trough all the subitems
            //and remove the checked state from them too
            for (z in 0 until menuItem.subMenu.size()) {
                val subMenuItem = menuItem.subMenu.getItem(z)
                subMenuItem.isChecked = false
            }
        }
    }
    // set item as selected to persist highlight
    selectedItem.isChecked = true
    // close drawer when item is tapped
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers()

    // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
    // For example, swap UI fragments here

    true
}
```

All the code is written in `Kotlin` but I think you won't have so much trouble to convert it to Java if you still use it. By the way if you have problems just ask :)

> PS: You don't need to specify `.setCheckable(true)` when you create a
>   new item. New items are checkable by default

Comment: Thanks. The XML specified by you solved my problems. However, a couple of improvements. 1) You don't need to "unselect" each item every time there is a click. Simply recording the previous checked item and unchecking it works. 2) setCheckable(true) is required - without that, the textColor, background stateList do not work i.e. the background drawable specified for when state=checked does not show when the item is checked.

Comment: 1) Yes sure, you can improve it as you want :)
2) That's really strange... (but ok)